# Combination of table and accordion where accordion unfolds under entire row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do intergrate accordions : http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

to my table (made out of divs)
I want the panel that unfolds to be the entire width of the row.

Idealy I'd like to avoid adding class/id to each pannel and button but instead automate the process just as W3Schools suggested.

However many alterings of their Jquery script have yielded no success for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/qSe6t/361/

```
 for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.parent().next().toggle("show");
  }
}
```

Thank you.

EDIT : i've been hacking away a it and I've made progress (change the adreess in the fiddle to 362) : 
I know it's the basic element that's supposed to be 0px and the lala that's supposed to be 500px but if I do that with the current code it seems to exectute the folding even though it's already folded so nothing happens.

Comment: I've edited it http://jsfiddle.net/qSe6t/362/

Comment: a tentative solution is hiding the elements on page load : http://jsfiddle.net/qSe6t/364/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(this).parent().next().toggleClass('show');
```

`toggle` affects visibility. `toggleClass` toggles a class on and off. You also have to wrap the object with jQuery to use jQuery methods, which is why I added the `$(this)`.

Comment: This does nothing for me (taking the lala-> show change into account)